# Chain Single independent requests with RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a method to add an item to my account:

```
 fun addItem(@Body addExperience: AddItem): Single<Item>
```

at some point the user can select multiple items and then add them all in bulk to his account. I want to chain these independent calls with RxJava2 (possibly in parallel) and then use the result of each to increment a progress bar.

Problem is --- i have no idea how to do it! Would this possibly be a Flowable? how can I generate this flowable from the multiple singles?

Comment: you can use if more than 1 singles `concatWith()` else `toFlowable()` and return a flowable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Flowable.fromIterable()` and `flatMapSingle()` each request. You can notify user about progress because after each request there is call to `subscribe`'s onNext.

```
List<Single<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Single.just(1));
list.add(Single.just(2));
list.add(Single.just(3));
list.add(Single.just(4));

Flowable.fromIterable(list)
        .flatMapSingle(singleRetrofitRequest -> singleRetrofitRequest, false, 2)
        .subscribe(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

As you can see I added additional parameters to `flatMapSingle()` to express how many requests in parallel are possible.